# Should I use iframes to change the contains of a div when clicking on menu?

Tags: iframe

Ok, this is a beginner's question.

I have a main page with a header (with a menu), a right column and a footer. I want these elements to be always present on my site, only the container div to change upon clicking different links in the menu. Until now I have used iframes. Is there any other way to do this without iframes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. But not with only HTML.
If you are using php it is common to do something of the sort:

inc/header.php:

```
<html>
 <head>
 ...
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   ...
  </header>
  <div id="content">
```

inc/footer.php:

```
 </div>
 <footer>
   ...
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
 include('inc/header.php');
?>
 <h1>Hello World!</h1>
<?php
 include('inc/footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it depends on what language you are using.

iFrames are a bad way to do this since your pages won't be indexed properly by search engines.  People will arrive on you iframe page and miss the context of your header and menu.

If you are using PHP you can create includes for the header, footer and right column as separate files.  So your page might look something like this:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
<p>Page content here</p>
<?php
include 'right_column.php';
include 'footer.php';
?>
```